# Can regular expression assert that 2 of submatches to be equal?

Tags: regex

Let say for this simple regexp,

`(?P<first>\d+)\.(?P<second>\d+)`

it can match strings like "123.456" so that,

`first -> 123, second -> 456`

Based on this example, is there a way to assert "first" should equal "second", otherwise the input string won't be a match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture the first digits before the dot in a capturing group and  use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) after the dot to group 1:

[`(?P<first>\d+)\.(?P<second>\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/Dt26kf/1)

Or you can referer to the first capturing group by [name](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

[`(?P<first>\d+)\.(?P<second>(?P=first))`](https://regex101.com/r/eZTeLl/1)

As per comment from [UnbearableLightness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3390419/unbearablelightness) you could use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` or use anchors `^` and `$` to assert the start and the end of the line.

[`\b(?P<first>\d+)\.(?P<second>(?P=first))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/eZTeLl/2)

Comment: You need to use anchors otherwise it will match something like `123.1234`.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness You are correct. I have added that to my answer and upvoted yours as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can backreference to the matched group in capture one with expression:

```
^(?P<first>\d+)\.(?P<second>\1)$
```

You can check it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/K4eCCm/2).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!